# Which is the correct preposition: at or from?

Tags: prepositions

People often use this term

> I will be working from home tomorrow.

Is it the same as I will be working at home tomorrow? How does using at in place of from change the meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work *at* home and *from* home at the same time. Working *from* home usually implies a virtual presence in the office via the Internet.

Comment: I agree -- it seems to be about the expectation and the nature of the work being done. If I choose to grade papers, I will work at home. If I login and and file my grades via the portal I will be working from home.

Answer (score 0):

They can both be used even at the same time. I would say that when using the word "from" It implies that you are doing work in your home for a larger organization, or company that also exists outside of your home. If you are working "at" home, then it could mean you are doing any kind of work, at your house. You could be working for a job or just doing chores around your house. Those are, I think, the implications of the different words.